# Accessing a URL stored inside a textarea field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically allow users to store URLs inside a textarea field within a form which is then stored in an Oracle DB field.

My question is, when they reference this record that holds this url, they would like to be able to hover over the URL, click on it and open up in a new browser window. At the moment, it is just a text string where the user has to copy and paste this link into a web browser.

Any ideas on what the best approach is to allow the user one click access to this stored link using JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: You could write an anchor tag to the page when you retrieve the data from the database.  I would recommend a target of "_blank" so that it open in a new tab.  But to give you more information, we need to know what language you are using to retrieve the data?

Comment: Why are you displaying it as a <textarea>? Is it so they can edit it?  But somehow you want them to also be able to click it?  As Stefan said, why don't you render a link next to the text area?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the TEXTAREA with Editable DIV. On click of div, you need to identify the element under pointer and invoke your custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Should it be a textarea? Could you use the rich text editor?

You might be find some jQuery rich text editor [here](http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors)